# My end point GMSMarker do not show on google map view

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have implemented `GMSMarker`, in that my end point GMSMarker do not show on google map view.

```
- (GMSMarker *)markerWithPath:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)path Index:(NSUInteger )index IconName:(NSString *)imageName {

    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:path[index]];
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    marker.flat = YES;
   return marker;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you set marker.map = GoogleMapView;

Comment: you have to add all markers to NSMutableArray and then you can show all markers on googlemap based on that array

Comment: `markerWithPath` method's first argument type is `CLLocationCoordinate2D  `or `GMSPath` ?

Comment: 1.I have set :"endPointMaker.map = self.googleMapView";

Comment: 1.I have set :"endPointMaker.map = self.googleMapView"; 2.The data of NSMutableArray <GMSMarker *> is from an method "for .. in" from server;3.The private method of "markerWithPath..." parameter  path is type of CLLocationCoordinate2D * or not GMSPath.